# RPi extremely slow download speed

Tags: networking, performance

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi as a small home server, and I am having issues with my download speed. My Windows PC is getting up to 6mb/s, the Raspberry Pi is doing a dist-upgrade, and is peaking at 80kb/s, but mostly is at < 30kb/s. Its plugged in with a short cable into my router, im connecting to it via SSH, which also works perfectly.

edit: Its booting from a SD card I was given with the RPi, sudo hdparm -t /dev/root is giving me 22.7 MB/sec, so its not the SD card being a bottleneck, also no other periphery plugged in.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Are you using a VPN? Is the Pi connected at 100/Full duplex? Are you using a slow mirror when updating? Do other downloads seem slow?

Comment: Like everybody suggests. Try download another file from a different server using wget but you can try a different LAN cable - it could possibly be faulty. Also try different port in your router. Even if its not 100mbit you will atmost have 10mbit (1.25mb/s)

Comment: I used a torrent and that solved it for me

Answer (score 8):

Generally it's the problem of mirror selection. The GEO-based mirror selection sometimes does not work well.

So mannually edit your `sources.list` file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can find proper mirror site here:
http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors

Comment: Potential easy fix: I had this problem when installing from NOOBS recovery and it was caused by using Google DNS on my router. I changed my routers DNS to my ISPs DNS, and it selected the right mirrors.

Comment: Thank you kindly, this solved my issue immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the obvious out of the way first: *bad connection speed(s)*.

With the below command, use [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net) to test out your connection speeds on your rPi.

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

[image: Testing connection speeds on an rPi]

If the above command yields good results & you're still suffering from indecent connection speeds, reboot your router(s), switch(es) and modem; basically your whole network.

If still problematic, you've landed on the worst case of having a faulty rPi.

Comment: you have https test link? coz this test was fine in my raspberry but this https is very slow " curl -sSL install.domoticz.com | sudo bash -x "

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same exact same problem right now, 8 months after this question is asked. But I have found a solution for this, and I manage to successfully install PIXEL desktop environment on my RetroPie in a matter of minutes.

First, edit the `raspi.list` file :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Comment out all the existing lines (including the archive.raspberrypi.org of course). Then add the following line :

```
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```

Save the file, then execute apt-get update and continue what you intended to do. Yes, I know, it might be a server located somewhere in China, but at least they are having a much lower server loads than the raspberrypi.org archive. 
I hope this helps answer other complaints about how slow the speed of raspberry pi debian archive server is.

Answer (score -1):

Very old question, but found the best answer somewhere else:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/39922/how-do-you-select-the-fastest-mirror-from-the-command-line

You don't have to do any searching anymore - as ajmitch has explained, you can use deb mirror to have the best mirror picked for you automatically.

apt-get now supports a 'mirror' method that will automatically select a good mirror based on your location. Putting:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

on the top in your /etc/apt/sources.list file should be all that is needed to make it automatically pick a mirror for you based on your geographical location.

Lucid (10.04), Maverick (10.10), Natty (11.04), and Oneiric (11.10) users can replace precise with the appropriate name.

Comment: Have you tested this on a Pi? Looks like it's for Ubuntu.